# WordPress using wp_editor in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, tabs, tinymce

Making a WordPress plugin, using WordPress 3.5.2

I'm using `wp_editor()` on the front end, inside jquery UI tabs `[ajax loading tabs + 2 editors on the same panel]`, and I'm getting the following error, when clicking `visual`.

> switchEditors is not defined

I've even tried adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582764/tinymce-with-ajax-tabs); it errors out tinyMCE is not defined.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: still looking for a better way out, the way i have tackled this is bringing the tinyMCE to the first tab, and making it a static tab instead of an ajax tab ( the rest of the tabs are still ajax), works well. I would still need this as ajax also. would appreciate tips if any.