# Couldnt edit tinymce content after second init

Tags: tinymce-4

I am creating a single page application which loads all content via ajax respective to the user events. The problem is, am having two different textareas loaded via ajax, and initialized by tinyMCE and neither is editable when the other is initialized. Both of them are drawn perfectly and all the menu options are clickable but they are only editable when only one of them is initialized.I am using the latest version of tinymce( version 4.1.7)

the tinymce.min.js file is loaded before ajax calls.

i am using following script to init tinyMCE

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: "#id"
         });
```

The file with script is loaded via ajax

```
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: uyrlToJS,
            cache:true,
            dataType: "script"
        });
```

I have tried removing old one and adding new instance
    `tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, "id2");
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, "id1");`

The textarea is in a bootstrap modal. so i also tried this function

`$(document).on('focusin', function(event) {
            if ($(event.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });`

none of them solved my problem, please help me resolve this.

Comment: Am not sure but this could solve your problem.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582764/tinymce-with-ajax-tabs#answer-7584778

Comment: @skt sorry dat didnt help